# Signing message: Provided address is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address which can't be converted

Tags: metamask, signature

[Provided address is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address which can't be converted](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31488/provided-address-is-invalid-the-capitalization-checksum-test-failed-or-its-an) is not a dupe, this is about signing messages

My code:

```
const msgParams = [{
        type: 'string', name: 'Message', value: 'Hi, Alice!'  
     },{   type: 'uint32', name: 'A number', value: '1337'
      }];
      let from = Merchant.accounts[0];
      console.log(window.provider);
      let p = window.provider;
      console.log(Object.keys(window.web3));

      window.web3.eth.sign(from, msgParams, function(err, res) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(res);
      });
```

(window.provider is the current provider.. window.web3 loses its current provider, see my other question [window.web3.currentProvider is null](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36559/window-web3-currentprovider-is-null) for details)

Running this I get the error in the title

Metamask prompted to sign.. once. Now the prompt won't show. The signing prompt did have the Alice, 1337 data in it.

How do I sign a message with Metamask to get the encrypted string of that signed message?

EDIT: Merchant is my utility class for Metamask. The logged output of Merchant.accounts[0] is

`0x2e290a50d3193753f156e5b0b12e4231bd568526`

EDIT 2: I have tried this:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(a,b) {
      Merchant.accounts = b;
      // alert("Saving accounts" + Merchant.accounts);
      console.log("Merchant accounts: " + Merchant.accounts);
      let x = web3.eth.getBalance;
      console.log(x);
    });



 toChecksumAddress (address) {
    address = address.toLowerCase().replace('0x', '')
    var hash = createKeccakHash('keccak256').update(address).digest('hex')
    var ret = '0x'

    for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
      if (parseInt(hash[i], 16) >= 8) {
        ret += address[i].toUpperCase()
      } else {
        ret += address[i]
      }
    }

    return ret
  }

reloadKeys() {
        const msgParams = [{
        type: 'string', name: 'Message', value: 'Hi, Alice!'  
     },{   type: 'uint32', name: 'A number', value: '1337'
      }];
      // Merchant.accounts[0]
      // let addr = 0x2E290A50d3193753F156e5b0b12e4231Bd568526;
      let from = this.toChecksumAddress(Merchant.accounts[0]);

      // window.web3.utils.toChecksumAddress();
      console.log(typeof(from));
      console.log(from);

      console.log(Object.keys(window.web3));

      window.web3.eth.sign(from, msgParams, function(err, res) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(res);
      });
```

I still get this error.

Comment: Have you tried `0x2E290A50d3193753F156e5b0b12e4231Bd568526`? (That has the correct capitalization checksum.)

Comment: What.. is the difference?

Comment: The difference is the capitalization.

Comment: @smarx I tried let addr = "0x2E290A50d3193753F156e5b0b12e4231Bd568526";
      let from = this.toChecksumAddress(addr);   window.web3.eth.sign(from ... same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two issues:

1. In Web3.js 1.0.0, the order of the parameters is `web3.eth.sign(dataToSign, accountToSignWith, callback)`, but you're passing the account to sign with first.
2. I don't think there's a way to sign objects like that, though maybe you know something I don't?

Try this to start with:

```
web3.eth.sign(web3.utils.sha3("test"), '0x2E290A50d3193753F156e5b0b12e4231Bd568526', function (err, result) { console.log(err, result); });
```

Make sure that works and then move on from there to signing what you want.

**EDIT**

Per https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/1530, `personal_sign` may be a better option:

```
var fromAddress = '0x2E290A50d3193753F156e5b0b12e4231Bd568526';
web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
  method: 'personal_sign',
  params: [
    web3.utils.fromAscii('hello world'),
    fromAddress,
  ],
  from: fromAddress,
}, function (err, result) {
  console.log(err, result);
});
```

**EDIT2**

Better yet, [`eth_signTypedData`](https://medium.com/metamask/scaling-web3-with-signtypeddata-91d6efc8b290):

```
web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
  method: 'eth_signTypedData',
  params: [
    [
      { type: 'string', name: 'Message', value: 'Hi, Alice!' },
      { type: 'uint32', name: 'A number', value: 1337 }
    ],
    fromAddress,
  ],
  from: fromAddress,
}, function (err, result) {
  console.log(err, result);
});
```

Comment: Hey, I'm able to sign a message when I switch the 2nd param to be one of my addresses! So I will mark this as correct for now. However, if I change the first parameter to a regular string eg. "test", when I click sign Metamask stays stuck spinning (odd). My intention behind this process is to sign a message proving that the message signer is the address they claim they are

Comment: I believe the data to be signed has to be 32 bytes. When I try with a shorter string and inspect the MetaMask popup, I see an error logged to the console: "message length is invalid". See https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/1530.

Comment: Thanks, I don't get an error just a pinwheel in metamask

Comment: If you right click on the MetaMask popup and click "inspect" and then view the console, you should see an error there that, when expanded, has the message I mentioned.

Comment: Also, please see my edit. Based on that GitHub issue, you may prefer to use `personal_sign`. The UI is much better.

Comment: Right clicking won't work  -- no menu on Metamask. On Mac, maybe that's why. (I just checked the regular console from developer tools)

Comment: Strange. I'm also on a Mac. In any case, I think we know the issue.

Comment: And see my second edit for using `signTypedData`, which seems to be what you were after.

Comment: Cool, so I can signTypedData to verify a message, then recover with `sigUtil.recoverTypedSignature({ data: msgParams, sig: result.result })`

Answer (score 1):

Signing requires a checksummed address which can be generated using the web3 function `toChecksumAddress`.  So your code needs to be adjusted as follows:

```
let from = web3.toChecksumAddress(Merchant.accounts[0]);
```

The checksum is calculated by capitalising certain hexadecimal letters according to the algorithm designed by Vitalk in [EIP-55](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-55.md)

Comment: Hello. web3.toChecksumADdress is not defined. `web3.eth.iban.checksum

var i = new web3.eth.iban("XE81ETHXREGGAVOFYORK");` is from the documentation ...  I don't see a clear way to use it

Comment: You might be using a beta version of web3 1.0.0. If so, `web3.utils.toChecksumAddress` instead.

Comment: Hi @smarx , I am using beta and I tried `web3.utils.toChecksumAddress`. I get the same error.

Comment: @smarx looks like there is a way to sign objects. https://medium.com/metamask/the-new-secure-way-to-sign-data-in-your-browser-6af9dd2a1527 , https://github.com/danfinlay/js-eth-personal-sign-examples << seems to work  on the signing part, need to test verification

Answer (score 0):

The Remix transaction result address, that I copy to use as contract, in fact, are not  valid anymore to web3 as contract hash (I don't know why). I went to etherscan.io and see [all transactions from my address](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x99d68b730560ad897e74610c2f04c2060438d851), click on the [last "contract creation"](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xf75e9aeabec365058c11cb348fe77c4bf2991112) that give me a different address than remix output.

I used that address and that error ends.

---

1 - Remix output hash from contract: 0x866e8ea2987873e4a0b985a5f408181c2b476cc9cf74f41dbb1e5e2231633821
2 - [Etherscan transaction detail](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x866e8ea2987873e4a0b985a5f408181c2b476cc9cf74f41dbb1e5e2231633821)
3 - **Contract address: [0x525d67ef6a08ad80c0956ca04af7eb2cd02a8bf0](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x525d67ef6a08ad80c0956ca04af7eb2cd02a8bf0)**

Comment: #1 is the TX Hash. Transaction result != contract address

Answer (score 0):

had a similar problem, try copying the address directly from bscscan and passing it as a string e.g '0xE60000' no need for conversion again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).